# react JS mapping data through an object

Tags: reactjs

I have an API that's returning me the categories and subcategories of 6 different stores when trying to map data i get the error Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at Function.entries () I tried to console log the data I keep getting undefined however accessing the network from dev tools I can see there's a response

this is my code:

```
function FetchedData() {
 const [data, setData] = useState();

 const getApiData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
  `https://api/admin_stats`      
 ).then((response) => response.json());
 
 setData(response);
};

useEffect(() => {
 getApiData();
// eslint-disable-next-line
}, []);
```

this is how I'm mapping thru data

```
<Section className='address-section first-secion' title="Loblaws" defaultExpanded="false">
                        {data ?
                          <>
                          <Section className='address-section first-secion' title="Baby" defaultExpanded="false">
                            {Object.entries(data?.loblaws).slice(0, 6).map(([key, val], i)  => (
                              <div className='OrderList-data-container-inner' key={i} >
                                <h2 className='OrderList-Cart'style={{fontWeight:'600'}}> {key}: <span style={{marginLeft:'30px', fontWeight:'500'}}>{val}</span> </h2>         
                              </div>
                            ))} 
                          </Section>
        : null}
 </Section>
```

this is the data

[image]

Comment: check it before mapping as `data && data.map()` or you can keep an `[]` as initial state and do `data.map(...)` ...  if its an object then `data && Object.entries(data).map(...)`

Comment: Do you try to do `map` inside the `FetchedData` or outside?

Comment: inside i edited the question to include how i'm mapping data

Comment: because `data` is not an `object` ...

Comment: add a use effect on data et display it only when it s not empty ?

Comment: also, data looks odd , do you want to map only through the first element of response ?

Comment: no i only gave an example loblaws i kinda did that to all the other stores

Comment: I mean the first object and second object have different key's

Comment: i managed to fix the problem by creating a new variable and just setting response[0] to data and response[1] to the new variable dataJson